# How would I hide a table row if its <td> elements don't have one of two classes?

Tags: jquery

I need to hide all of the rows in a particular table whose td elements do not contain one of two classes.

If at least one of the td elements in a row contains one of these two classes, then don't hide it. Otherwise, hide the entire row.

```
class='class1'  
class='class2'  
id='mytable'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the markup for the table, including examples of rows that should be hidden, and rows that should not be hidden. Also, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an example it's difficult to know exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps something like this would work (air code):

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    var count = $('td.class1, td.class2', $(this)).length;
    if (!count) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach, perhaps it is not the shortest one, but hopefully clear to follow. Lookup find, hasClass, eq methods in jQuery to learn more.

```
var trs = $("table tr")

for( var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
    var tds = $(trs.eq(i)).find("td");
  var trToKeep = true;
  for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
    if (tds.eq(j).hasClass("x") || tds.eq(j).hasClass("y")){
        trToKeep = true;
      break;
    }
    else {
        trToKeep = false;
    }
  }
  if (trToKeep === false) {
  trs.eq(i).hide();
  } 
}
```

Working jsFiddle is here (classes you would look for are x or y):

https://jsfiddle.net/Turo/aj55q33w/

---

**Update:** Updated my answer as you wanted to hide the ones that do not have the classes, not the ones that do.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the rows and check the class of each `td`. I have loop through and used array and flag to decide whether to show or hide. I also hide all at first then show them later with condition check.

```
var classNames = ['red', 'green'];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
    var show = false;
    $(this).hide();
    $('td', this).each(function() {
      var tdClass = $(this).attr('class');
      if ($.inArray(tdClass, classNames) != -1) {
        show = true;
      }
    });
    if (show) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```